# Informatica creates duplicate records on a Teradata set table with a primary index ( direct SQL can not )

Tags: teradata, primary-key, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Very simple source->target insert, source records are treated as "Insert", target transformation uses the "Insert" function only. Target Teradata table is a set with a primary index defined. Informatica target trans also has a primary key defined. Teradata informatica relational connection does not have a "bulk" option.

So how come Informatica does create a duplicate record, while even a direct insert into Teradata can not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is is a *Unique Primary Index*? Otherwise only duplicate *rows* are considered equal.

Comment: This sure did the trick, thank you Dieter!

Comment: If you're defining a unique primary index, there is no need for the added overhead of a set table, FYI.